# Marshalling a domain class to 2 different JSONs

Tags: jaxb

I have a requirement to produce different JSON from one of my domain classes without changing the current JAXB annotations. The only way that comes to mind is to extend my domain class and  marshal this subclass.

Is there any other way to achieve this? Perhaps special annotations supplied by JAXB implementations?

Hope I was clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You can use the JSON binding in the MOXy JAXB component of EclipseLink 2.4.  You can apply one mapping using standard JAXB (and extended) annotations, then apply more mappings using the mapping document extension.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html

**Download EclipseLink 2.4.0 (milestone development builds)**

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/milestones.php

Comment: I've developed a Grails project and as far as I recall I had some problems using MOXy with it.I'll give it another try.